# How do I extend SymPy pretty printing for new structures in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy, mathjax, pretty-print

**Note:** This is a duplicate of [this question in Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3786168/how-do-i-extend-sympy-pretty-printing-for-new-structures-in-jupyter-notebook).  I had to first pose the question in Math StackExchange because [StackOverflow doesn't have MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106281/mathjax-should-also-work-in-stackoverflow). However, almost all SymPy questions are on StackOverflow. Please refer to the Math Stack Exchange version for the typesetting of the desired output.  An editor on Math StackExchange suggested I cross-post it here.

In Jupyter notebook if we execute this code:

```py
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()
x,y=sp.symbols('x,y')
x**2+sp.sin(y)
```

We will get a nice output, with no further coding, due to [SymPy's pretty printing process](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html), that looks like

[image: Pretty formula]

Now suppose we do:

```py
class MetricSpace:
    def __init__(self, M, d):
        self.M = M
        self.d = d
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"$({self.M}, {self.d})$ {self.__class__.__name__}"

Re,d=sp.symbols(r'\Re,d')

MetricSpace(Re,d)
```

Then the output we get is

[image: ugly formula]

If we do instead

```py
from IPython.core.display import Markdown
Markdown(repr(MetricSpace(Re,d)))
```

then I get the desired output, which looks like

[image: Desired formatting]

How do we code the above so that SymPy's pretty printer provides the desired output in Jupyter notebook without having to wrap it in `Markdown(repr(...))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet that functions correctly. It might not do quite all the things
you want yet, but hopefully it will start you off.

```py
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()

class MetricSpace(sp.Expr):
    def __init__(self, M, d):
        self.M = M
        self.d = d

    def _latex(self, printer=None):
        return f"({printer.doprint(self.M)}, {printer.doprint(self.d)})\\ \\text{{{self.__class__.__name__}}}"

Re, d = sp.symbols(r'\Re,d')

MetricSpace(Re, d)
```

See [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html) for more
information on the Sympy printing system and how to hook into it. The key things
to note is that you should subclass `Expr` if you want your object to come into
the domain of Sympy's pretty printing, and that the latex printer calls the
`_latex` method to get its LaTeX. It doesn't need to be wrapped in dollar signs,
and you should use `printer.doprint` to get the LaTeX of nested expressions.

Here is a screenshot of what this produces on my notebook:

[image: screenshot]

PS: I'm intrigued by a metric space with underlying set denoted by "`\Re`". If
you mean the reals, might I suggest using `sp.Reals`?

Comment: Izaak, the other side of the coin is how to do dynamic checking of types in Python.  "typen" package solves that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343360/dynamic-checking-of-type-hints-in-python-3-5/63344681

Comment: For a metric space, I want to say that M is a nonempty set.  So I need a way of annotating sp.Reals to say that it is a nonempty set.  To do that I have to at least wrap sp.Reals with a "Reals" subclass which is also a subclass of a made-up class I call NonemptySet.

Comment: So something like this: `class MetricSpace:
    
    @strict_type_hints
    def __init__(self, M: NonemptySet, d: Metric):
        self.M = M
        self.d = d
        
    def _latex(self, printer=None):
        ...`.  The third side of the coin is that where applicable I want to start using the Category Theory features in sympy.

Comment: Subclassing `Basic` would make more sense, `Expr` gives you operator overloads you don't want.

Comment: In sympy 1.7, you can subclass `sympy.printing.defaults.Printable`

Comment: _"and you should use `printer.doprint` to get the LaTeX of nested expressions."_ - the docs [specifically call out](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html#common-mistakes) not to do this.

Comment: Eric thanks for this extra info.  I am on SymPy 1.6.1 now but will remember this advice when I get to SymPy 1.7.

Comment: @Eric can you post an additional answer which revises the first answer for SymPy 1.7 new features?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I have already accepted the answer from Izaak van Dongen above.  This answer is to provide context for the question for those that may be interested.

I was reading a book on SDEs and I asked [a question on the measure theory presentation of probability space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3760724/what-is-the-probability-space-of-typical-real-univariate-probability-distributio).  There are a large number of structural definitions involved.  I wanted to use SymPy to organize them and present the type signatures in something mimicking [Axiom style](https://www.cs.ru.nl/E.Poll/talks/axiom.pdf).

To do this pleasantly in Python 3 and SymPy I needed a few things:

- A way of dynamically enforcing [function signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343360/dynamic-checking-of-type-hints-in-python-3-5).
- A way of pretty-printing complex algebraic type signatures (this question).

I started implementing the definitions.  To check that they were organized correctly, I asked

- A question about [extending the concept of distribution function to any ordered space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780089/extending-the-concept-of-distribution-function-to-any-totally-or-partially-order), which naturally arose in formalizing the definitions for probability space.  I don't think anybody got, outside of the SymPy formalization context, why this question was natural or interesting.
- A question [confirming that my stack of definitions for probability space was correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785531/construction-of-the-steinhaus-probability-space) (without bringing SymPy into it).

With that in hand, and the above solution for the pretty-printing, the following few definitions give the style of my solution (without quoting the whole thing which is about 85 definitions):

```
import sympy as sp  # I am at version 1.6.1
from typen import strict_type_hints, enforce_type_hints
from traits.api import Array, Either, Enum, Instance, Int, Str, Tuple

class Concept(sp.Expr):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        
    def _latex(self, printer=None):
        return f"{self.name}:\\ \\text{{{self.__class__.__name__}}}"

class NonemptySet(Concept):
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        if value==sp.S.EmptySet:
            raise ValueError("Set must not be empty")
        super().__init__(name, value)
        
    def _latex(self, printer=None):
        return self.name

class Reals(NonemptySet):
    
    @strict_type_hints
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = sp.symbols('\\Re')
        super().__init__(self.name,sp.Reals)
        
    def _latex(self, printer=None):
        return self.name

class SampleSpace (NonemptySet):
    pass

class Algebra(NonemptySet):
    
    @strict_type_hints
    def __init__(self, 
                 name: sp.Symbol, 
                 Ω: SampleSpace, 
                 A: Either(NonemptySet, sp.Symbol)):
        self.Ω=Ω
        super().__init__(name, A)

    def _latex(self, printer=None):
        math=str(self.name).replace('$','')
        math2 = self.Ω._latex(printer)
        return f"{math}:\\ \\text{{{self.__class__.__name__} on }} ({math2})"

class Algebra(Algebra):
    
    @strict_type_hints
    def __init__(self, name: sp.Symbol, Ω: SampleSpace, A: Algebra):
        self.Ω=Ω
        super().__init__(name, Ω, A)

class EventSpace(Algebra):
    
    @strict_type_hints
    def __init__(self, name: sp.Symbol, Ω: SampleSpace, A: Algebra):
        super().__init__(name, Ω, A)

class AdditiveFunction(Concept):
    
    @strict_type_hints
    def __init__(self, 
                 name: sp.core.function.UndefinedFunction, 
                 Ω: SampleSpace, 
                 A: Algebra, 
                 f: sp.core.function.UndefinedFunction):
        self.Ω = Ω
        self.A = A
        super().__init__(name, f)

    def _latex(self, printer=None):
        math2 = self.A._latex(printer)
        return f"{self.name}: {self.A.name} \\to \\Re \\ \\text{{{self.__class__.__name__} on }} {math2}"
```

and so on.  Any comments or suggestions on a more "SymPy-thonic" way of improving the above sketch would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI @Izaak van Dongen

Comment: FYI @Nate Eldredge

Comment: FYI @Error - Syntactical Remorse

Comment: FYI @Oliver Diaz

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is integration with Jupyter notebook, then you want the IPython `_repr_latex_` hook:

```py
class MetricSpace:
   def _repr_latex_(self):
       # this is text-mode latex, so needs $ to enter math mode
       return f"$({self.M}, {self.d})$ {self.__class__.__name__}"
```

This will make `MetricSpace(...)` show as latex in a jupter notebook, and is completely independent of sympy.

---

Separately, `sympy` has a `latex` function. If you want to support that, you need to implement `_latex`:

```py
class MetricSpace:
   def _latex(self, printer):
       # this is math-mode latex, so needs \text to enter text mode
       # if the class members support this hook, you can use `printer._print` to recurse
       return f"{printer._print(self.M)}, {printer._print(self.d)}$ \text{{{self.__class__.__name__}}}"
```

This will make `sympy.latex(MetricSpace(...))` work.

---

Finally, there's the sympy integration that connects these two modes together, after `init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')` is called. This has changed between Sympy 1.6 and 1.7.

- In Sympy 1.6, an ipython latex formatter is provided for

  - subclasses of `sympy.Basic` (and some others)
  - `list`s, `set`s, etc of those objects
- In Sympy 1.7, an ipython latex formatter is provided for

  - subclasses of `sympy.printing.defaults.Printable`
  - `list`s, `set`s, etc of any object that implements `_latex` or subclasses `Printable`

Subclassing `Expr` is a bad idea, as that adds tens of possibly meaningless methods and operator overloads to your class. Subclassing `Basic` is less bad, but suffers from a lesser version of the same problem if your class is not intended to be used within sympy